# Extract values from a property file using bash

Tags: bash

I have a variable which contains key/values separated by space:

```
echo $PROPERTY 

server_geo=BOS db.jdbc_url=jdbc\:mysql\://mysql-test.com\:3306/db02 db.name=db02 db.hostname=/mysql-test.com datasource.class.xa=com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource server_uid=BOS_mysql57 hibernate33.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect hibernate.connection.username=db02 server_labels=mysql57,mysql5,mysql db.jdbc_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver db.schema=db02 hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver uuid=a19ua19 db.primary_label=mysql57 db.port=3306 server_label_primary=mysql57 hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

I'd need to extract the values of the single keys, for example **db.jdbc_url**.
Using one code snippet I've found:

```
echo $PROPERTY | sed -e 's/ db.jdbc_url=\(\S*\).*/\1/g'
```

but that returns also other properties found before my key.
Any help how to fix it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused because you are using the substitute command (`sed s/.../.../`), so any text before your regex is kept as is. Using `.*` before `db\.jdbc_url` along with the begin (`^`) / end (`$`) of string marks makes you match the whole content of the variable.

In order to be totaly safe, your regex should be :

`sed -e 's/^.*db\.jdbc_url=\(\S*\).*$/\1/g'`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Also other answers were ok but I've chosen your reply as "correct" as it fixed the bug in the original expression.

Answer (score 2):

If `db.name` always follow `db.jdbc_url`, then use `grep` [lookaround](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html),

```
$ echo "${PROPERTY}" | grep -oP '(?<=db.jdbc_url=).*(?=db.name)'
jdbc\:mysql\://mysql-test.com\:3306/db02
```

or add the VAR to an array,

```
$ myarr=($(echo $PROPERTY))
$ echo "${myarr[1]}" | grep -oP '(?<=db.jdbc_url=).*(?=$)'
jdbc\:mysql\://mysql-test.com\:3306/db02
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, quite interesting

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` for this, like so:

```
echo $PROPERTY | grep -oE "db.jdbc_url=\S+" | cut -d'=' -f2
```

The regex is very close to the one you used with `sed`.
The `-o` option is used to print the matched parts of the matching line.

**Edit**: if you want only the value, cut on the '='
**Edit 2**: `egrep` say it is deprecated, so use `grep -oE` instead, same result.  Just to cover all bases :-)

Comment: This will capture `db.jdbc_url=` as well. I think OP only wants the value

Comment: I fixed it.  And it will always work, even if "db.name" does not follow the db.jdct_url like in the other answer.