# In bash extract select properties from a standard property file to a single delimited line?

Tags: bash, key-value

**In bash**:

1) For **a given `groupname`** of interest, and
2) **a list of `keys`** of interest, for which we want a table of **values**, for this **groupname**,
3) read in a **set of files**, like those in `/usr/share/applications` *(see simplified example below)*,
4) and produce a delimited table, with one line per file, and one field for each given key.

---

### EXAMPLE

#### inputs

We want only the values of the **Name** and **Exec** keys, from only `[Desktop Entry]` groups, and from one or more files, like these:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Root
Comment=Opens
Exec=e2
```

..

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=Close
Name=Root2
```

#### output

Two lines, one per input file, each in a delimited `<Name>,<Exec>` format, ready for import into a database:

```
Root,e2
Root2,
```

---

Each input file is:

- One or more blocks of lines delimited by a [some-groupname].
- Below each [.*] is one or more standard, unsorted key=value pairs.
- Not every block contains the same set of keys.

---

*[Forgive me if I am asking for a solution to an old problem, but I can't seem to find a good, quick bash way, to do this.  Yes, I could code it up with some while and read loops, etc... but surely it's been done before.]*

---

Similar to [this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52481733/extract-values-from-a-property-file-using-bash) but more general answer wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `awk` is your option, would you please try the following:

```
awk -v RS="[" -v FS="\n" '{     # split the file into records on "["
                                # and split the record into fields on "\n"
    name = ""; exec = ""        # reset variables
    if ($1 == "Desktop Entry]") {
                                # if the groupname matches
        for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) { # loop over the fields (lines) of "key=value" pairs
            if (sub(/^Name=/, "", $i)) name = $i
                                # the field (line) starts with "Name="
            else if (sub(/^Exec=/, "", $i)) exec = $i
                                # the field (line) starts with "Exec="
        }
        print name "," exec
    }
}' file
```

You can feed multiple files as `file1 file2 file3`, `dir/file*` or whatever.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you.